# Can a serial port be left in a dirty state?

Tags: linux, serial-port, posix

I'm writing a program to communicate with an existing device via serial port, and I am noticing a weird pattern. This is being tested with both a real serial port, and a USB-to-serial adapter. I get the same results for both.

Immediately after booting up the computer or plugging in the adapter, serial port communication works fine. I can send binary data to the device, and get a response back. The program can continue to communicate with the device as long as it wants.

However, once the program ends (cleanly closing the port), running the program again results in failure to communicate. It can access the serial port just fine, but all it gets back is garbage.

(Oddly, the garbage appears to be binary data mixed with modem commands like ATE0Q0S0=0, which makes no sense. Again, I don't need to reset the device to communicate with it, just the port, so I don't know where this is coming from.)

Power-cycling or unplugging the device has no effect. It is only when I reboot the computer, or reset the USB device (via unplug, or driver reset), that I can run the program once more and get it to communicate successfully.

What would cause this? From the results, I can only assume that the serial port is not being left in a clean state after use, but I can find no documentation about properly cleaning the serial port state, other than re-applying ioctl attributes and closing the file descriptor after use, both of which I already do.

Maybe a serial port pin gets left on or something? I don't know how I would test for that, or why it would even happen.

My current "solution" is to just stick with the USB adapter, and have my program perform a USB driver reset before attempting to use the serial port, but I'm hoping there is a better solution.

**Edit**

As requested, here is the C program I'm using to test the serial port read/write.

## include

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Saved termios that we can re-apply when we exit
struct termios savedPortAttributes;

// Set the serial port attributes so we can use it
void setPortAttributes( int fd )
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset( &tty, 0, sizeof(tty) );
    if ( tcgetattr( fd, &tty ) != 0 ) {
        printf( "tcgetaddr error: $i\n", errno );
        return;
    }
    cfsetispeed( &tty, B9600 );
    cfsetospeed( &tty, B9600 );
    cfmakeraw( &tty );
    tty.c_lflag = 0;
    tty.c_oflag = 0;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;
    if ( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0 ) {
        printf( "tcsetaddr error: $i\n", errno );
        return;
    }
    if ( tcflush( fd, TCIOFLUSH ) != 0 ) {
        printf( "tcflush error: $i\n", errno );
        return;
    }
}

void test( int fd )
{
    // Send a sample MODBUS command
    printf( "Writing command\n" );
    char sendBuffer[] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x02, 0xB5, 0xC9 };
    int bytesWritten = write( fd, sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer) );
    if ( bytesWritten < 0 ) {
        printf( "Error writing command.\n" );
        return;
    }

    // We don't want to wait more than 1000ms for a response
    struct timespec spec;
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec );
    int64_t startMs = spec.tv_sec * 1000 + round( spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6 );

    // Read data back from the port
    printf( "Reading from port...\n" );
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    int bufferOffset = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while ( 1 ) {
        count = read( fd, &buffer[bufferOffset], sizeof(buffer) - bufferOffset );
        if ( count < 0 ) {
            printf( "Error reading command.\n" );
            return;
        }
        if ( count > 0 ) {
            printf( "Bytes read: " );
            for ( int i = bufferOffset; i < bufferOffset + count; i++ ) {
                printf( "%02x ", buffer[i] );
            }
            printf( "\n" );
        }
        bufferOffset += count;

        // Test code. If we receive part of a valid MODBUS response, grab the
        // field length byte so we know if we're done reading
        if ( bufferOffset >= 3 && buffer[0] == 1 && buffer[1] == 3 ) {
            int messageLength = buffer[2];
            if ( bufferOffset >= messageLength + 5 ) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // If it's been 1000ms, stop reading
        clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec );
        int64_t timeMs = spec.tv_sec * 1000 + round( spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6 );
        //printf( "%" PRId64 " , %" PRId64 "\n", startMs, timeMs );
        if ( timeMs - startMs > 1000 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    printf( "Opening port\n" );
    int fd = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY );
    if ( fd == -1 ) {
        printf( "Unable to open port.\n" );
        return;
    }

    tcgetattr( fd, &savedPortAttributes );
    setPortAttributes( fd );

    test( fd );
    test( fd );

    tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &savedPortAttributes );
    close( fd );
}
```

Comment: tried a different brand/model of usb-serial? there's a ton of them out there, and most of them are ultra-cheap crap. wouldn't be surprised if it turns out to be a hardware problem.

Comment: @MarcB But I get the same result from the computer's real serial port as well. Wouldn't that suggest that it isn't a hardware problem?

Comment: If a process opens a port it can release that port by closing it at any time. The OS will then reclaim the port. If the process ends without releasing the port, the OS will eventually reclaim the port but it'll take a few minute. I'm wondering if the OS is not reclaiming the port. Also is your program actually closing the port properly and is it exiting correctly?

After the program exits you could try sending commands via the commandline: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/how-to-send-data-to-a-serial-port-and-see-any-answer

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to open and close the port? Also a snippet showing how you transmit and receive to the port.

Comment: The most plausible explanation is that your program is not performing a complete initialization of the serial port for its use. I.E. your program relies on the clean boot, or quiescent state.  Nor does your program apparently restore the termios state as it found it.   As @Jeff mentions, you need to post your code. *"Wouldn't that suggest that it isn't a hardware problem?"* -- Correct, so why does the title suggest otherwise?

Comment: @sawdust I have updated my post to include the code. I do attempt to setup the termios attributes at port open, as well as restore them before closing. However, since I'm new to this and figuring it out from documentation, I'd be happy to learn if a code change fixes the issue.

Comment: Your code looks much better than I expected.  You need to check the return code of **tcsetattr()** and **read()** syscalls for errors.  Try adding `rc = tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);` at the end of **setPortAttributes()**.   Also, I suggest that the read loop should not break solely because 1000ms has elapsed; if the message length is valid and data is being received, then the loop should continue.  Use the output of shell command `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 --all` before and after each execution of your program to detect any changes.

Comment: Also try changing the **open()** options to `O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY`

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for the suggestions, I have updated the code. Unfortunately the changes made no difference. Program works once, then I have to reset the USB adapter to get anything but garbage. I also ran the stty command before and after, and it's results are identical. Though apparently running stty also does something to the port, as my program doesn't work when run immediately after, requiring a USB reset for that as well.

Comment: @sawdust Something odd I noticed. When I took a look at the garbage I was receiving from the serial port, intermixed with the binary were a series of modem AT commands. What the heck? No idea where that comes from. Again, resetting the USB adapter makes that stop until I finish reading real results.